# What are Harry, Ginny, Ron and Hermione's professions?

Tags: harry-potter

After the end of the Second Wizarding War Harry Potter later married Ginny Weasley, and the couple had three children of their own: two sons James Sirius, Albus Severus, and one daughter Lily Luna. What are Harry and Ginny's professions? I heard that Harry became an Auror, but what about Ginny, Ron, and Hermione?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Harry became an Auror under the new Minister of magic Kingsley Shacklebolt and Ginny became a professional Quidditch player for the Holyhead Harpies.

> Harry Potter, who always voiced a desire to become an Auror, or someone who fights dark wizards, was named head of the Auror Department under the new wizarding government headed by his friend and ally, Kingsley Shacklebolt.
>
> His wife, Ginny Weasley, stuck with her athletic career, playing for the Holyhead Harpies, the all-female Quidditch team. Eventually, Ginny left the team to raise their three children – James, Albus and Lily – while writing as the senior Quidditch correspondent for the wizarding newspaper, the Daily Prophet.

[J.K Rowling Beyond the Epilogue](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/jk-rowling-goes-beyond-the-epilogue.html)

From the same Chat transcript.

> An often asked question is what are Harry, Ron and Hermione doing now? J.K. said that Harry, along with Ron, is working at the Auror Department at the Ministry of Magic, and after all these years, Harry is now the department head.
>
> "Harry and Ron utterly revolutionized the Auror Department," Rowling said. "They are now the experts. It doesn't matter how old they are or what else they've done."

Comment: There's also [the new "article"](http://www.today.com/books/read-j-k-rowlings-new-post-latest-harry-potter-gossip-1D79887288) that confirms their occupations.

Comment: @phantom42 Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Just to confirm Simon's excellent answer, Ginny's profession is an "active" Quidditch reporter, as the current Pottermore content features numerous articles "written by Ginny Weasley" from the [current (2014) Quidditch World Cup](http://insider.pottermore.com/2014/05/the-2014-quidditch-world-cup-route-to.html)

Answer (score 6):

According to *The Cursed Child*

Harry is the department head of Magical Law enforcment.

> But if the Head of Magical Law Enforcement isn’t reading his files — HARRY: But I don’t need to read it — I’m out there, hearing about it.

Hermione is the minister of Magic

> HERMIONE: I mean it, Harry, I will not be Cornelius Fudge on this one.
>  I will not stick my head in the sand. And I don’t care how unpopular
>  that makes me with Draco Malfoy.

Ginny edits the sports column for the daily Prophet.

> DRACO: Really? Doesn’t your wife edit the Daily Prophet?
>
>  GINNY steps towards him, outraged. GINNY: The sports pages!

Ron works for the Weazly wizard wheezes

In alternate Timeline 1 Hermione is a Professor, the Defense against the Dark Arts professor.

In alternate Timeline 2, Hermione and Ron are professional freedom fighters.

Comment: And in the alternate timelines?

Comment: @Valorum should that be a separate question? as when this was asked alternate timelines didnt exist. (serious)

Comment: Since you're already talking about HP:CC, you might as well just add them in

Comment: @Valorum kk, will add